# VBA Outlook - GetTable error 91: object variable and with block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to get table from Outlook email and copy it to Excel using VBA.

There is an error `91: object variable and with block variable not set` in the line below. I have been using the getCurrent() function in other modules and it works fine.

```
Set oTable = oConv.GetTable
```

**My VBA code:**

```
Public objApp As Outlook.Application

Sub ReadTable()

Dim oTable As Outlook.Table
Dim oConv As Outlook.Conversation

Set oConv = GetCurrentItem().GetConversation
Set oTable = oConv.GetTable

End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
        Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    Case "Inspector"
        Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
End Select

Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is in Excel.

In Tools | References add Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

The error means MailItem.GetConversation() returns null. This can happens for the brand new messages (retrieved from objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem in your code).
You must check the return value instead of assuming that you will always get back a valid object.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the oConv object was not set correctly/initialized. The [GetConversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869870(v=office.15).aspx) method of the MailItem class returns null if no conversation exists for the item. No conversation exists for an item in the following scenarios:

- The item has not been saved. An item can be saved programmatically, by user action, or by auto-save.
- For an item that can be sent (for example, a mail item, appointment item, or contact item), the item has not been sent.
- Conversations have been disabled through the Windows registry.
- The store does not support Conversation view (for example, Outlook is running in classic online mode against a version of Microsoft Exchange earlier than Microsoft Exchange Server 2010). Use the IsConversationEnabled property of the Store object to determine whether the store supports Conversation view.

So, if any of these statements is the case, your code will fail.